# ¿Como corregir el siguiente error ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'selenium' al ejecutar un archivo python?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

El chromedriver ya se encuentra en la ruta `C:\`, a pesar de ello no lo esta reconociendo.

```
from selenium import webdriver  
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException  
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains  
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By  
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys  
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
```

El error en la consola PS

```
PS C:\Users\mb\Desktop\Automatizacion.py>   C:/Users/mbrios/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python310/python.exe c:/Users/mb/Desktop/Automatizacion.py/cancelación.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\mb\Desktop\Automatizacion.py\cancelación.py", line 17, in <module>
    from selenium import webdriver  
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'selenium'
PS C:\Users\mb\Desktop\Automatizacion.py>
```

Comment: tienes instalado selenium?. Si no es así  puedes hacerlo de la siguiente manera, `pip install selenium `

Comment: Dios no te he pedido nada pero por favor haz que los usuarios hagan el [tour] y lean [ask] y que sepan que el código **no** va en imagen

Comment: @Christian incluso les aparece un aviso a la derecha cuando revisan la pregunta y lo ignoran, es increíble :/ Si el que lee mi comentario es el que publicó la pregunta, te recomiendo leer [esta publicación en meta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2990/un-fragmento-de-c%C3%B3digo-vale-m%C3%A1s-que-mil-im%C3%A1genes-c%C3%B3mo-sensibilizar-a-los-usu) que dice por que nos es tan importante que el código no esté en una imagen.

Comment: Hola, Bienvenid@ al Sitio, veo que eres nuev@ te recomendaría hacer el [tour] para que conozcas mejor el sitio, He mirado tu post y te comento lo siguiente:, Puedes leer este Articulo [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, Puedes leer este Articulo [mre] y te recomiendo que expliques que hace tu código y que esperas que haga, También es importante que sepas que preguntas son mal vistas [help/dont-ask].

Answer (score 0):

La solución al error es primero validar que se instalo correctamente selenium.  Después validar que el interprete sea el mismo que el de la versión de selenium, para que puedan reconocer ambos el mismo directorio en el que se instalo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]